# Unable to install grpc-tools via npm or yarn on mac m1 chip?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, apple-m1, grpc-node

Commands Used to install:

> npm install -g grpc-tools

> yarn add global grpc-tools

While trying to install grpc-tools on mac m1 BigSur. I ran into errors pasted below:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/abdulmoiz_ahmer/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/grpc-tools
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install
npm ERR! response status 404 Not Found on https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc-tools/v1.11.2/darwin-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/abdulmoiz_ahmer/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/grpc_tools.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc-tools/v1.11.2/darwin-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc-tools/v1.11.2/darwin-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: response status 404 Not Found on https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc-tools/v1.11.2/darwin-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/abdulmoiz_ahmer/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/grpc-tools/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/install.js:67:15
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.4.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/abdulmoiz_ahmer/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node" "/Users/abdulmoiz_ahmer/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/grpc-tools/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/abdulmoiz_ahmer/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/grpc-tools
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 13):

I made it work by setting explicitly the npm_config_target_arch to x64, this is probably not the best solution but for now that's all I found. I ran my `npm install` like this:

```
npm_config_target_arch=x64 npm i grpc-tools
```

if I find a better way I'll update that answer.

Comment: Thank you! 'npm_config_target_arch=x64 npm ci' worked for me

Comment: It also works perfectly fine for yarn `npm_config_target_arch=x64 yarn add grpc-tools`

Comment: This is the best answer for me!

Comment: @clément-jean - I just want to make sure I understand this solution.

The problem is the owners of grpc-tools have not compiled an arm64 binary 

So for the scope of this command-line we're overriding the npm_config_target_arch environment variable to x64.   After this command completes - the environment variable npm_config_target_arch will be reset to what it was before running this command?

I'm not a shell expert - but don't you need to use two ampersands to make that environment setting stay in scope? example:

test=blah && echo $test

Comment: @Tim You are right that after executing `npm_config_target_arch=x64 npm i grpc-tools`, the npm_config_target_arch variable will be reset. If you want this variable to persist (as long as your shell session), you can use the `&&` operator but I generally prefer using a semicolon like so: `npm_config_target_arch=x64; yarn add grpc-tools`. If you want that variable to persist across reboot, you will have to set that in a file like .bashrc or whatever your shell uses.

Comment: One thing I realized is that you can't actually use the x64 on an arm64 machine - so this really just "works around the npm install" issue - i.e. npm install will complete successfully - but the binary on your machine will not be executable

Comment: @Tim You are right on the fact that this is a workaround. However, the binary is executable. You can try the protoc binary like this `./node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/protoc` once you installed it in your nodeJS working directory.

Comment: I don't think that is true.

I don't think you can run binaries built for x64 on arm64.

And it is confirmed when I try it in my docker container:

root@17079a4c0395:/usr/src/app# ./node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/protoc
bash: ./node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/protoc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: @Tim When running `uname -p` I get `arm`, so my architecture is arm and when I run `file ./node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/protoc`, I get `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64` so the binary is x64. And I can run it. This might depend on OSes, not really sure for your case.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to work around it by just forcing the x64 binary and letting BigSur deal with it:

```
yarn add grpc-tools --ignore-scripts
pushd node_modules/grpc-tools
node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install --target_arch=x64
popd
```

If anyone can find a normal way to install it that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
# Open terminal in x86_64 mode:
arch -x86_64 zsh
source "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"
# Install any another version of node (will be installed x86_x64 version):
nvm install v14
npm install -g grpc-tools
```

It is [problem](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2187) with package grpc-tools.
One of solution for today is using Rosetta. Recommend [good tutorial](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#macos-troubleshooting).